# Red color in terminal not working

Tags: shell, colors, terminal, command-prompt, prompt

I have a problem with my terminal. I'm unable to print the red color !
In my .bashrc this works :

```
export PS1='\t \[\033[01;32m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") \[\033[01;34m\]$\[\033[00m\] '
```

But when i try this command directly in the terminal i got a white text :

```
echo -e "This is red->\e[00;31mRED\e[00m"
```

When I try with light red I got light red :

```
echo -e "This is light red->\e[01;31mLIGHT_RED\e[00m"
```

Already tried to change the background/text color in profile preference.

Thank you,

Comment: Works for me!  (Maybe, try in a new terminal window.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something with your terminal settings, since the code you sent is correct. I get:

[image]

and my settings are:

[image]

and I use Konsole on KDE4.

Comment: Thanks this helped me ! I don't know why but, my red color was well Red for the column "Color" but white for the column "Intense color". This explain why I've got the red color in the PS1 but not in the echo.